# Objective C: Format a String Outlet

Tags: objective-c, string, formatting

is it possible to format the .stringValue property of a NSString outlet without creating extra variables ??

```
@property (retain) NSString *myString;
@property (retain) NSString *myStringLabel;
```

-

```
@synthesize myString;
@synthesize myStringLabel;

myString.stringValue = myStringLabel.stringValue  

/* but I want to format it with %.0f
   so I don't get any fractional digits */
```

I am currently playing around with sliders and the values are of format 1.123312
I want to display only the leading number.

Comment: What's wrong with intermediate variables?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with them, I am just asking if it is possible.

Comment: The phrasing of your question is a little misleading, as it doesn't appear to have anything to do with outlets. Perhaps you meant 'properties'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input string is something that can be represented as a float :

```
formattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.0f", [inputString floatValue]];
```

or if you wanted to round the value instead :

```
formattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", round([inputString floatValue])];
```

I'm not sure why you would want to do this specifically on one line though?

Comment: It's not that I "need" or want to do it. I was just asking if it were possible. But I assume the answer would be no. I will just accept your answer, since I don't think its possible.